# Potential energy of and forces within a massive spring

Tags: potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, spring

So, I've been doing problems related to calculating the time period of SHM for a spring mass system where the mass is M, and the spring has a finite mass m.

The standard method of dealing with this seems to be to replace the system by an equivalent system consisting of a mass-less spring with an attached mass (M + m/3).

I do understand how the kinetic energy of the spring is derived. 
However, I do not see how this makes the above mentioned two systems equivalent. I'm having trouble seeing how the forces will vary within the spring. 
Also, I don't see how the potential energy would still be $kx^2/2$, for now that the spring has mass, and it is a non-rigid body, the work done by the internal forces within the spring should be non-zero, right? Also, if the work done by the internal forces in the spring were to be zero, the various parts of the spring wouldn't be able to acquire any velocity.

Comment: If you have a spring with a spring constant k and it is compressed by a distance x, then the potential energy of the spring will be $kx^2/2$ regardless of whether the spring has mass or not. Why would the mass or mass density of the spring affect the internal stresses in the spring?

Comment: Yes it is still will be kx^2 /2 .  When the energy is released it will move the mass and the mass of the spring, so kinetic energy will 1/2 m v^2 of mass plus 1/2 m v^2 of spring mass.